# List expansion while using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am learning Python and, during an exercise, I got into this situation:

```
words = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for w in words
    if len(w) == 5:
        words.insert(0,w)
```

Now, what happened here was that while the loop was iterating over the last word and found a match, it inserted the new word at the beginning of the list and continued the loop as the length of the list has increased by 1. This resulted in an infinite loop.

Now, I changed the code like this:

```
words = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
for w in words[:]
    if len(w) == 5:
        words.insert(0,w)
```

The result was exactly as I anticipated. There was only one word addition at the beginning and exited the loop.

Can someone explain what exactly was happening in the first code?

Comment: Exactly what you already said.

Comment: The main difference is that "words" will reference your original list, whereas words[:] returns a >new< list that you iterate over. That means that you will not edit the same list that you iterate.

Comment: why not make a copy of `words` and do the insert under the loop? manipulating the list under a loop is normally a bad idea.

Comment: Anzel: that is exactly what words[:] does.

Comment: :) What i assume is that in the second piece of code, at run time, the list was expanded and the variable took each element for each iteration. But i want to know why this did not happen in the first piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterated over the list which you modified in the loop. Bad idea in most cases.

Perhaps what you are missing is that `words[:]` creates a copy of `words`. You iterate over the copy so when you add to the original list everything is fine.

Comment: Well, what i assume is that, coming from C background, in the first instance, for each iteration, (address of first element)+(iteration count) and since there is element added at the beginning, it always picks the last element and continues in an infinite loop.

Comment: @SunilReddy Under the hood there is a loop `for (int i = 0; i < length(lst); i++) { ... }`. When you add an element `length(lst)` is incremented and since you add to the front, then i'th element is now (i+1)'th. In next iteration you hit the same element. Thus the condition is again true and you get an infinite loop. If that's what you've meant then yes. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will sleep in peace :)